# Program buttons G7 and G8 on the Logitech Gaming Mouse G502

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, logitech

I wanted a few extra programmable buttons on my mouse to assign shortcuts to, so I picked up a Logitech G502.

I am using xbindkeys and xev according to numerous tutorials available to find the button numbers and then assign actions to them.

However, I find that inexplicably, the buttons marked G7 and G8 (two buttons to the left of mouse button one) seem to already be hardcoded to control-c and control-v.

I would very much like to "unbind" these from those behaviors and assign different ones to them, but as they seem to already be sending rather important key codes to x-windows, I can't override them with xbindkeys because that would interfere with/override normal control-c control-v operation.

As the mouse comes with a windows app to program all the keys, so I assume that control-c/control-v is *not* hardcoded within the mouse firmware, I can only imagine that someone has decided that the logitech mouse driver in the Linux kernel (if there is such a thing) will interpret button presses as keys 37 + 55 (2 keys) and 37 + 54.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

And sorry: Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon)

Also note these are *not* the "forward" "backward" buttons that are typically operated by the thumb and are assigned to b:8 and b:9. They are *additional* buttons operated by the index finger very close to button one, but like forward/backward, are also in a front to back arrangement.

Edit:
Actually it *was* hard coded in the mouse. It was a case of RTFM. The mouse has a few built in profiles which can be cycled through by clicking the scroll button to the left. However, the preset profiles do not include one that just outputs button clicks for those buttons. It is either control+c/v or else they control mouse DPI. I'm going to have to setup a Windows install somewhere and run the included software to see if I can't override those profiles.

Comment: Did you try using windows to re-program it? Did that work? (Perhaps you can self-answer, now?)

Comment: You could try using [Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper), it lists support for the G502.